Is it possible for viscosity to increase with concentration of a nano material in a polymer solution without any increase in storage or loss moduli?
I am introducing small amounts of nanocellulose (<5%wt) to aqueous gum Arabic solutions (<20%wt.) I found that the viscosity increases with nanocellulose concentration but the storage and loss moduli are relatively unaffected. Is this possible?
